# Developing for Windows 7 and above

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, window

I want to make an Windows Desktop Application for Windows 7 and above.

Can someone tell me how can I start? I have tried searching on Google for developing apps for Windows; all I’ve found so far is UWP (Universal Windows Platform) which I believe works for Windows 10 and above. I have even checked the Microsoft docs and all they are telling is about Windows 10 apps, not a word about versions below it.

Can someone tell me if I make an app for Windows 10 will it work with earlier versions too? As the main requirement is developing for Windows 7.

I have been doing coding for 3-4 years so I know coding. I just want to start from right path. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Jason is right to a point, UWP is the modern way,  but I would actually recommend WPF which was designed to replace Windows Forms.

It uses modern techniques and methods  with C# like Caml for the UI layout, MVVM, View Model bindings etc, and it's all transferable skills into UWP and Xamarin mobile apps.  As an aside Xamarin Forms are looking to build out WPF apps in future releases for true cross platform apps so it's a good framework to learn for Windows desktop.

Start here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I will definitely follow this. Also one thing I just found is ElectronJS which lets me build cross platform apps. Is it good?

Comment: Never used it, but guessing it's one of many JavaScript to 'some other' framework languages, C# and WPF is one of the native ways of doing Windows apps, the 'proper' way if you like - but just my opinion

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will definitely look into this. It's possible to make Windows Desktop app on Mac?

Comment: At the moment, broadly, no, but keep an eye on Xamarin Forms, it achieves that currently for mobile apps and is moving towards this as I type

Comment: hmm... dang.
Will install Windows on Mac then! That's why I am not seeing Windows Form App in Visual Studio New Project Templates!

Answer (score 2):

You are right that UWP is for Windows 10 and above, so I would stay away from that in your case.

What you should start with is a simple basic Windows Form development in C#.

Download and install Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition from here:  https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Then I suggest looking for tutorials online for Windows Form apps in C# which can guide you through it.

Here are a couple that could help.

http://www.guru99.com/c-windows-forms-application.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGHzNunW8M8

There are more but they are for older VS Studio versions, but the principals are the same even if the UI is a bit different.

The DotNet Framework takes away a bit the dependency upon a specific windows version.  As longer as your windows version can run the DotNet Framework version you are targetting (compiling for) then it will work in most cases.

Best to first find out which DotNet framework version is installed on your target PC and then build for that, or upgrade it.

It might look a bit different on different windows version, so if you are compiling on a different platform to what you are running on then it is best to make sure that you do testing on your target platform.

This shows how to change your target DotNet version in Visual Studio:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E36kiGWfGCQ

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I will definitely follow this. Also one thing I just found is ElectronJS which lets me build cross platform apps. Is it good?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know it.  Any cross platform program will have disadvantages compared to a native program, but if you really need cross platform it is good.  However, I would not consider Windows 7 -> Windows 10 to such be a different platform that you need such a program.  This is more targetted at people who need to develop for windows & linux & mobile etc.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Thanks for those links, really helpful. Can't I make windows app using Mac?

Comment: This might be useful:  https://stormpath.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-using-visual-studio-on-a-mac

Comment: Thanks. Great link. :)